# SNMP v2 Community String Rules

Tags: networking, snmp

I just have a simple question and I'm having a hard time find the answer. I'm curious if there are standards for what a community string can and can't be for SNMP v2. I'm mostly concerned with if there are any rules about it being an empty string or having trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking there are no restrictions on valid characters/symbols because the community string is defined as **OCTET STRING**. But most of the equipment vendors do have restrictions. Here is the Cisco policy for that: *"The name can contain up to 32 characters and can contain any combination of alphanumeric characters, hyphens (-), and underscore characters (_)"*

Comment: That's what I was looking for thanks. I'll have to check the product I'm working with and see if there are any guidelines.